# Capturing Multiple Time Zones in Sharepoint

Tags: date-time

I need to capture multiple time zones in our Sharepoint site. Ideally I would like to enter AEST and have the other files calculate/convert to the various other timezones. Is there a way I can do this? I know about the calculated option in the field menu but I don't know how to get it to recognise it's a time. Eg. 23:00 = 2:00 to be 01:00 not 25:00.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use UTC time and work the calculation on it.

The problems will be happen when the day light savings change as each regions daylight savings are different.